# Why does the same Ajax request not always take the same time?

Tags: ajax, csv, console, performance-testing

I have a CSV file that I am fetching with Ajax. I am trying to measure how long it takes to fetch and parse the file from localhost. But the result differs for every request. Since I am fetching the file from the same (local) server every time, why does the Ajax request not always take the same time?

```
console.time('myTimer');
d3.csv('myFile.csv', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.timeEnd('myTimer'); // 44 ms, 65 ms, 75 ms etc.

})
```

Also, how can I accurately time the request time in order to measure performance gains I get from reducing the file size?

Comment: I personally think that trying to do some load-balancing or benchmark with something that acts asynchronously, is quite impossible/hard stuff; if you ask this, it means that you don't understand how AJAX works under the hood and that is indeed an async technology.

Comment: Could you explain why the async nature of Ajax affects the results of the timing test above, given that the snippet above is the only operation on the whole page?

Comment: Moreover, even if I just loop through an ordinary array, the timing result differs every time.

Comment: If you fire a task, which means that you are simply asking to do something to someone, without fixing any timeline or predictable behaviour, how you pretend to measure and give a rationale in terms of performance over the time to the response that you will eventually receive ? The time is a variable with no mathematical law attached to it. Sometime an user is filling the bandwidth with a lot of traffic and in another given moment he is just browsing text ...

Comment: also anything in-between, from your servers to the local network is performing differently at any given instant, plus any browser has its own issues with running JS in a decent way.

Comment: You try to benchmark in a range of some `ms`. There are so many things in between that could happen on a mulity threaded system. Other programs running could do some task in between. Some other IO could take place in between influencing the result ... With such low time values you most likely _benchmark_ some system dependen and browser dependent things then the actual request/code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. With the help of them, I found this enlightening blog post on the subject. http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/